# モデルのリレーションに関して[UserモデルとOneToOneで紐づけたモデルからデータを取得したい]

Tags: python, django, database

タイトルに関してお伺いしたいです。宜しくお願い致します。

環境

- Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda, Inc.
- Django              2.1.7
- django-allauth      0.39.1

---

djangoの作成目的：日報管理を行うアプリを構築

⬛︎プロジェクトの構成
Report
 |
  --accounts_app
 |
  --result_app

⬛︎モデルの構成
accounts_app.models
 ・Region
 ・Department
 ・UserProfile(OneToOne=>User)
　  - (department)=ForeignKey(Department)

result_app.models
 ・ResultReport 
    - (owner) = ForeignKey(User)
    - (department)= ForeignKey(Department)

この、`ResultReport`内の`department`フィールドの`default`を、`UserProfile`の`department`に設定したいのですが、adminサイトでデータの追加を見るとうまくいっていません。

⬛︎現在試していること

(report.models)

```
from accounts.models import Region, Department, UserProfile
class ResultReport(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, default=User.username, ・・・・省略)
department = models.ForeignKey(Department, default=str(UserProfile.user_region, ・・・・省略)
```

◆　コードは動くのですが、、（最初、`makemigrations`すると、下記のエラーを吐き、
`ValueError: Cannot serialize：django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForwardManyToOneDescriptor object at 0x105de3e10`、取り合えず`str()`で囲んだら`migrate`できたのですが、、）
反映されていません。

ひとまず動くので手動でもいいとは思うのですが、、どこをどうすれば良いかわからず質問させていただきます。
※　appを分けているのはall-authを使ってみたくてtutorialをすすめて、accountsappを作成しただけなので特に理由はありません。
※　`User.username`も拾わないので、、何か勘違いがあるのだと思っています。ご教示いただければ幸いです。

何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`models.py` と `admin.py` の実際のコードを見ないと確かなことはわかりませんが、 `default` はそのような使い方はできないのではないでしょうか。

そのようなことをしたい場合は `ResultReport` の `save()` メソッドを上書きしてコードで設定するようにする必要があるものと思います。

Comment: こちらもお答えいただきありがとうございます！はい。まったく使い方を間違っていたようで、その後作成を続けていくとわけのわからないエラーが出て動かなくなり3時間ほど無駄にしてしまいました、、、そして、こちらを答えていただいていることに気づき、該当箇所を削除したところ、、先へ進むことができました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: そうでしたか、先に進まれたとのことで、よかったです :)